# Can I track an engagement where the fiancé died before marriage on Ancestry.com?

Tags: ancestry.com, data-storage

I have a couple who got engaged before the future husband went off to WWII and never returned. How can I track such an event on Ancestry.com? (It would seem from the web site the assumption is that if a couple got engaged then they eventually got married, which isn't the case here.)

Answer (score 4):

The data experts and or Ancestry.com experts may have more to contribute on this topic, but I suspect you will need to apply a custom tag (or fact/event).

At least in *Family Tree Maker 2010 for Mac*, "engagement" is one of the optional tags (fact/event) in the "marriage group."

[image]

Certain events/facts/tags have particular genealogical significance. For example birth, marriage, and death. Genealogical software relies on the specific data about these "events" for many of the charts, reports and/or narratives developed.  Generically speaking, software programs may have a group of optional events/tags/facts that report about these genealogically significant items.

- Birth. We often don't have a birth record, but we might have a baptismal (christening) record that may act as a substitute; effectively, an equivalent for the significant genealogical purpose.
- Marriage. We might not have a marriage record, but have say the record of a marriage bann, engagement, license; or, as in the example, an annulment or divorce. These other records may serve as a substitute; effectively, an equivalent for the significant genealogical purpose.  **These different options are intended to imply that a union occurred.**
- Death. We might not have a death record, but have a burial record that serves as a substitute...

In your case, I suspect that you are trying to apply a tag/event/fact that is assigned to what is *Ancestry.com*'s "marriage group," and so Ancestry is treating it as a marriage record substitute/equivalent.

To achieve a different outcome, my suggestion is that you **add a custom event (say "Engaged")**. This will move the tag/event/fact away from selections that are reserved for the genealogically significant "marriage group." (In *Ancestry.com*, I suspect you will need to apply it separately to both the intended parties.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate event for engagement. You can create the event manually and then add a source through the "facts and events" tab.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it is asking for the person to whom they got engaged, and only list spouses as options (or lets me create a spouse.)

Comment: I don't think that the Ancestry data model notion of a spouse necessarily implies marriage, so I would be comfortable putting down the fiancee in that field.